# CSS Sub Navigation Issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a sub navigation menu under "Jewellery". The problem is I want a space between the two menus when they open. To achieve this I added "margin-top:5px;" to the sub navigation. It does create the space however as you can see as soon as I bring the mouse down to the sub navigation it becomes deselected.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
nav ul ul {
margin-top:5px;
background-color: #101010;
color: #FFF;


}
```

Link to jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/2mpcQ/4/

Comment: Rule #1 of menus: Do not add styles to the list itself, other than display/position/float. Put all other styling on the A-tag with display:block.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `padding-top:5px` and the black submenu inside this padded DOM Element

Answer (score 0):

border-top: 5px solid #fff;

This will give the appearance of space between the Menu and sub menu.
and will still give it functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can use div tag sub menu to get the desired vertical space. I have modified your jsfiddle for reference.

```
.rowheight {background: #fff; font-size: 5px;}  

 <ul>
  <li>
    <div class="rowheight">&nbsp;</div>
    <ul><li>Item</li></ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

jsfiddle link -

http://jsfiddle.net/2mpcQ/25/

or can use `border-top: 5px solid #fff;` for nested ul but it is not controllable. It will affect all nested UL tags.

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want just to solve this issue, try adding `border-top` to `.nav ul ul` (`border-top:5px solid #fff;`). Though, your question was "what's the correct way to achieve this?". I think the right way is styling the "a" element, as Diodeus said.